# kivy-buildozer error: Cython does not appear to be installed

Tags: android, python, cython, buildozer

I am trying to make an apk of my python-kivy gui using buildozer, but the process stopped with the error `error: Cython does not appear to be installed`

```
`/home/koushik/Desktop/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/build/python-install/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py:267: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'install_requires'
  warnings.warn(msg)
running build_ext
failed to import Cython: /home/koushik/Desktop/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/build/python-install/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_io.so: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32
error: Cython does not appear to be installed
# Command failed: ./distribute.sh -m "kivy" -d "rlc_and"
# 
# Buildozer failed to execute the last command
```

I don't understand this, because I have already installed cython, then why it is saying cython is not installed? How do I fix this?